# Interpolation between curve and line in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have two functions:

```
     x = seq(0, 3, len = 100)

     y1 = function(x){
           x^2 -2*x +2
        }
    y2 = function(x){
      -4*x + 1
        }
```

For finding an interpolation between two functions which gets positive values for the interpolation function, I know that

```
   (1-z)*y1(x) + z*y2(x)  = 0
   (1-z)*y1'(x) + z*y2'(x) = 0
```

then I know that  z = y1(x)/(y1(x)-y2(x)) so I got that

```
   2*x^3-10*x^2+16*x-12 = 0
```

and I use R for finding the root of above function:

```
   > polyroot(c(-12, 16, -10, 2))
   [1] 1+1i 1-1i 3+0i
```

or

```
   x  = uniroot(function(x)2*x^3 -10*x^2+16*x-12, lower= 0, upper = 3)
   $root
   [1] 3

   $f.root
   [1] 0

   $iter
   [1] 0

   $estim.prec
   [1] 0
```

then

```
   z = (x^2 - 2*x +2)/ (x^2+2*x+1)

  > z
  [1] 0.3125

  y3 = function(x){(1-z)*(x^2-2*x+2) + z*(-4*x+1)}
  y3(x)
```

but still y3(x) is negative is some parts, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of `2*x^3-10*x^2+16*x-12 = 0` and why are you finding it's roots?

Comment: At the end , we are looking for the roots of 2*x^3-10*x^2+16*x-12 = 0. But about z it is wrong , it can be also written as : z = y1(x) /[y1(x) -y2(x)].

Answer (score 0):

First, a condensed version of some of the code in your question.

```
x = seq(0, 3, len = 100)
y1 = function(x) x^2 -2*x +2
y2 = function(x) -4*x + 1
z = function(x) y1(x)/(y1(x)-y2(x))
```

Now some plotting for visualization.

```
plot(x,y1(x),ylim=c(-12,5),type="l",ylab="y")
lines(x,y2(x),col="blue")
lines(x,z(x),col="red")
abline(h=0,v=0,col="gray")
legend("bottomleft",c("y1(x)","y2(x)","z(x)"),fill=c("black","blue","red"))
```

[image]

For the reason why your y3(x) function is still negative, I think that's more of a math question than a programming question. Plotting y3(x), I do see that their are many negative values. I'm not too clear on the other parts of your question, so I'm not sure how to solve that part of your problem.